# SSH Key on remote repository. (Github or Bitbucket)

Tags: git, github, ssh, bitbucket

In either GitHub or Bitbucket what is the purpose setting up an SSH key on a remote repository? Is it so 3rd party systems or applications can connect to the repo without logging in?  Is there any additional security benefit in doing this?  Will this effect user's pulls, pushes, ext on that repo?

I've just recently started collaborating with other for the fist time ever on my project and would just like to follow the best security practices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it so 3rd party systems or applications can connect to the repo
>   without logging in?

No. Applications will log in using this SSH keys, but not with login or password.

> Is there any additional security benefit in doing this?

Yes. You do not need to leave your password on devices, which not belongs to you, if you need work on them. You can use various keys for different devices or applications, so if you need revoke access from your job PC, but continue use repo with home PC, notebook and other devices, you can only remove SSH key, which was used on job. Password change is not required, unlike the situation when login and password uses.